# How to find if records match or not

Tags: sql, matching

This is probably quite simple i just cant get my head round it.

I want to display a list of the customers that have a different city listed in their billing city versus their customer city. The billing address is in a table titled invoices and the customer address is in a table titled customers.

Is there a function that would show the ones that aren't the same?

This is probably quite simply i just cant get my head round it.

I want to display a list of the customers that have a different city listed in their billing city versus their customer city. The billing address is in a table titled invoices and the customer address is in a table titled customers.

Is there a function that would show the ones that aren't the same?

i can show the two tables together easily using a join but now i want to differentiate them

```
    select
    c.LastName,
    c.City,
    i.billingCity
    from Customers c
    inner join invoices i on c.customerId = i.customerId
```

Comment: What if there are two invoices for a customer, one with matching city, other without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option, using an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
    c.LastName,
    c.City
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoices i
              WHERE i.customerId = c.customerId AND
                    i.billingCity <> c.City);
```

If you want to also show the other non matching invoice city or cities, then you would need to stick with a join approach:

```
SELECT
    c.LastName,
    c.City,
    i.billingCity
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN invoices i
    ON i.customerId = c.customerId AND
       i.billingCity <> c.City;
```

Your main original problem was omitting a join condition.

Comment: Thank you so much! the AND <> was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind me asking; if I were to need the opposite and find all the values where the billingcity and the city specifically were the same what function would i use? in essence, what is the opposite of:  <> ?

Comment: Join on the condition `i.billingCity = c.City`